# Do not getting any data from mongodb database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ecmascript-6

first I am trying check. is my mongodb module is working or not. then i found that it does not getting any data from MongoDB Database.so i try to find error but i could not find error.

and there is an another error.it says `this.DB.close()` is not a function. it is in `conn()`  inside **MongoDB.js** file

**MongoDB.js**

```
// require("dotenv").config();
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
import { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } from "mongodb";
export default class Mongodb {
  D_NAME = null; //Database Name
  C_NAME = null; //Collection Name
  CLIENT = null; //mongodb object
  DB = null; //perform CRUD on DB
  URL = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGODB_USERNAME}:${process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD}@${process.env.MONGODB_HOSTNAME}/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`; //Connection URL

  constructor(database, collection) {
    this.D_NAME = database;
    this.C_NAME = collection;
    this.CLIENT = new MongoClient(this.URL, {
      serverApi: {
        version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
        strict: true,
        deprecationErrors: true,
      },
    });
  }
  
  conn() {
    try {
      // Connect the client to the server   (optional starting in v4.7)
      this.CLIENT.connect();
      // Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
      this.DB = this.CLIENT.db(this.D_NAME).collection(this.C_NAME);
      console.log("Connected");
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  async getData(query) {
    this.conn();
    try {
      console.log("Get Data");
      // console.log(query);
      return await this.DB.find(query);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    } finally {
      //this.DB.find();
    }
  }
  async setNewData(data) {
    this.conn();
    try {
      return await this.DB.insertOne(data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return e;
    } finally {
      this.DB.close();
    }
  }
}
```

router

```
import express from "express";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import Mongodb from "../Modules/Mongodb.js";
const router = express.Router();

router.post("/", async(req, res) => {
  let db = new Mongodb("sample_analytics", "accounts");
  console.log("test");
  let data =  await db.getData(req.query);
  console.log(data);
  res.send(data);
});

export { router };
```

**output **: {
"_events": {},
"_eventsCount": 0
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource—when trying to get data from a REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43871637/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-whe)

Comment: _"... `this.DB.close()` is not a function"_ It looks like `this.DB` is a collection.  I believe you want to instead _close the client_.